# The child node "resource_owners" at path "hwi_oauth" must be configured

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, oauth, hwioauthbundle

I'm using HWIOAuthBundle wit my symfony application and I followed the following documentation of theirs.
https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle

I got stuck at one place. As the resource owner I used google and when running the application it gives me this error

The child node "resource_owners" at path "hwi_oauth" must be configured.

Following is a sample of my code. Can someone help me out to resolve this issue.

[image is in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxLix.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
hwi_oauth:
    resource_owners:
        any_name:
            type:                google
            client_id:           12345678910                //your client Id
            client_secret:       012345678910               //your client secret
```

Comment: Is there any difference between the content in my code sample and this one. I'm confused